# Best way to control axis label position parallel to axis

Tags: r, plot

The axis labels for `plot`s in R default to the center of their respective axis. I would like to move the axis labels to the *ends of the axes* so that the horizontal "x" label is at the far right and the vertical "y" label is at the far top. What are some recommended ways to do this? Can one use `mtext` in a clever way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mtext` and playing with `adj` parameter:

```
plot(0,ann=FALSE)
mtext('right',side=1,line=2,adj=1,col='red',cex=2)
mtext('top',side=2,line=2,adj=1,col='blue',cex=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Somehow skipped over the `adj` argument in `?mtext`. These R parameters are nice to type, but not so nice for other things.

Comment: Any idea why `las=1` for the vertical axis label causes `adj=1` to be ignored?

Comment: My last comment has been posted as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24320017/1745884

Answer (score 2):

Using the `title` function you can also use the `adj` argument, and the text will be placed the same distance from the axis as titles are by default:

```
plot(0,ann=FALSE)
title(xlab="right",ylab="top",adj=1)
```

In fact, you can do this all from within the `plot` call too:

```
plot(0,adj=1,xlab="right",ylab="top")
```

[image]

Be aware that this second example will also right align the `main` title in the instance of something like:

```
plot(0,adj=1,xlab="right",ylab="top",main="yeah")
```