# R plot: How to use mtext to get top-aligned vertical label with las=1

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to get a label on my vertical axis using `mtext` that is read horizontally (`las=1`) and is at the top of the axis.

My attempt is to use `las=1, adj=1`. I can get the desired placement when I don't specify `las=1`, but as soon as I add the `las=1` argument the `adj=1` placement goes away. Here's a picture with code. The left plot shows correct placement, but without `las=1`. The right plot shows both arguments present.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(2,3,2,1))

plot(1, 1, ann=F)
mtext(col="blue", "y", side=2, line=2, adj=1)
mtext(side=3, "col=blue, side=2, adj=1")

plot(1, 1, ann=F)
mtext(col="red", "y", side=2, line=2, adj=1, las=1)
mtext(side=3, "col=red, side=2, adj=1, las=1")
```

[image]

I've tried fussing around with padj, but that only moves the label up & down a little. Also, I know that the `at` argument can, but that feels a bit too manual.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to access the height of the plot by calling `par('usr')[4]`:

```
par(mar=c(2,3,2,1))
plot(1, 1, ann=F)
mtext(col="blue", "y", side=2, line=2, at=par('usr')[4], las=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility using `text()`. Basically we are setting the x and y position but we are doing so in a way that will adapt to the plot as you change ranges and such. Thus you shouldn't have to change the code too much for different plot (only if you change the margin spacing)

```
par(mar=c(2,3,2,1))
plot(1, 1, ann=F)
mtext(side=3, "convertX/Y")
xx<-grconvertX(grconvertX(0, "nfc","inches") , "inches","user")
yy<-grconvertY(par("din")[2]-par("cin")[2]*5/2, "inches","user")
text(xx,yy,"y", col="green", cex=1.5, xpd=NA, pos=4)
```

For the x, we go all the way to the left of the figure region, and for the y, we go down just over two lines form the top. Then we draw our "y" value to that it is left aligned at that point.

[image]