# Adding text or title into R graph / plot

Tags: r, graph

Adding text to a particular location of a plot / graph in R.

Hello. I am making a series of plots in R. I want to conserve space so I wanted to remove the titles, which I previous had using the "main" command.

I want to put the titles right in the top middle of the plot/graph.

While looking online I found nice code to place text, as can be seen here: http://sphaerula.com/legacy/R/placingTextInPlots.html

```
##  par( "usr" ) returns a vector containing xleft, xright, ybottom, ytop.
usr <- par( "usr" )
##  Place the text. Note the use of the adj parameter.
##  Left top corner:
text( usr[ 1 ], usr[ 4 ], "left top",     adj = c( 0, 1 ), col = "blue" )

##  Left bottom corner:
text( usr[ 1 ], usr[ 3 ], "left bottom",  adj = c( 0, 0 ), col = "blue" )
##  Right top corner:
text( usr[ 2 ], usr[ 4 ], "right top",    adj = c( 1, 1 ), col = "blue" )
##  Right bottom corner:
text( usr[ 2 ], usr[ 3 ], "right bottom", adj = c( 1, 0 ), col = "blue" )
```

All these commands put text in a particular corner. I want to put it in the middle. Is there any advice on how to do this? A primitive way would be to add a lot of spaces to the text for the top left corner... but is there anything more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "middle" you mean "center top" the following should work:

```
text(x = median(c(usr[2], usr[1])), 
     y = usr[4],
     labels = "center top",
     adj = c(.5, 1),
     col = "blue")
```

Comment: May I ask one more question? If I were to move the label to the left of the graph, like, outside the graph... how should the code be changed? I see that using median you put it in the middle.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. Could you be more specific about what you would like your end result to be? Perhaps try the mtext() function if you want to put text in the margins.

Comment: So, I am making a multi-panel figure. There are multiple rows and multiple columns. Each row would correspond to a letter - such as A, B, C, etc... and only the first panel or plot.graph in each row would have this letter. 

I tried mtext. It puts the letter in line and parallel to the y axis. What I am looking for is something that would put it just a little bit left of the axis, and rotated at 90 degrees. So, that way the label A (or B or C, etc) would be beside the Axis, and would face upwards like it does on the X axis and on the title. 

Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Got it - thanks for the description. I think this depends on the framework (plotting packages) you are using. I would create a separate question about this!

Comment: Thank you for your help. 

I think it's solved now actually. Here's what I did: I tried using las, and got a bit closer. And then while searching I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320017/r-plot-how-to-use-mtext-to-get-top-aligned-vertical-label-with-las-1


I prefer your original answer over this one. But, after I asked the first question I was instructed to not do it that way, but either way, thanks again for helping me improve my R skills!